# How do I remove eval()?

Tags: javascript, eval

How do I remove eval in the code below:

```
var c = 4; // c can change

parseFloat(eval('document.formName.fieldName1' + (c + 1) + '.value * document.formName.fieldName2[' + c + '].value'));
```

I have tried objects, arrays, global window variables, nothing works when combined with the `document.formName` selector.

**UPDATE #1:** The answer marked as duplicate does not apply to my issue, as my code reads a form value based on the `document.form.field.value` selector. That solution didn't work. I have also tried objects, arrays and more.

Comment: You can write what is written in there as JS and not as a string.


What you have is a string that is being summed up with variables, so if you want that string to execute you need eval. However you really dont need to have this as a string.

Comment: Thank you, this was an old code, and I have already tried all available solutions. It's working now as per the answer below.

Comment: @Ciprian: The marked duplicate is correct. It explains the concept of accessing object properties with dynamic names.

Comment: It might be, but it didn't work for my code snippet.

Comment: How did it not work? It's the same concept.

Comment: I couldn't make it work. Maybe I didn't understand the concept, hence my question. In my case, I needed a code sample, not a concept. I am researching the concept now, based on the code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
parseFloat(document.formName["fieldName1" + (c + 1) ].value * document.formName.fieldName2[c].value);
```

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. I don't know why it works without a dot `.` before the field name, but it does.

Comment: @Ciprian There’s a dot accessor syntax and a bracket accessor syntax in JS.

Comment: You live and you learn. I'll Google the accessor syntaxes. Thanks.